# Why this 'instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\String, string given...' error?

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I am trying to generate `department name` from given `student-id`, in my controller. And try to save them in `database`. But i have found the following error message in `laravel` -
[image]

For saving data into `database`, the code is:

```
    protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'roll' => $data['roll'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'department' => $this->department($data['roll']),
    ]);
}
```

And the function `department` is:

```
    private function department(String $r)
{
    if($r.length() == 6)
    {
        $d = $r.charAt(3);
    }
    else {
        $d = $r.charAt(4);
    }

    switch ($d)
    {
        case '0': return 'CE';
        case '1': return 'EEE';
        case '2': return 'ME';
        case '3': return 'CSE';
    }
}
```

After `EDIT`: My updated classes is:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'roll' => $data['roll'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'department' => $this->department($data),
    ]);
}

private function department(array $r)
{   
    switch (substr($r['roll'], -3))
    {
        case "0": return "CE";
        case "1": return "EEE";
        case "2": return "ME";
        case "3": return "CSE";
    }
}
```

But it does not return any value for `department`.

Comment: try `department(\String $r)`?

Comment: don't put code into comments. it's unreadable. edit your question and put it there.

Comment: Thanks, question modeified.

Comment: This isn't a debugging service. Now that your original problem is fixed, you should ask another question, not just keep adding more questions on to this one. That means you need to learn how to do basic debugging yourself.

Comment: What is the `String` class meant to be? PHP doesn't have a `String` class by default, is it something you've defined? If you want to typecast it to a string, use `string` lowercase. Also, you can't call methods on a PHP object like `$r.length()`. Looks like you're trying to write JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `\String` PHP will recognize it as a class name, instead of a type-check.

Or you could just add `use String;` before the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

When you make method like this

```
private function department(String $r)
```

It means that your argument is variable named `$r` which is object from class `String` in current scope/namespace.

but, when you execute your method passing simple type `string` var

```
'department' => $this->department($data['roll']),
```

So, you need to check if your `String` class exists and then pass instance of it to your method